# "DexException: Multiple dex files define" using Weibo SDK

Tags: android, weibo

**Target:** integrate weibo sdk https://github.com/sinaweibosdk/weibo_android_sdk

Workflow: I created new project and added weibo sdk. After that ran the project and got compile error.

**weibo gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/weibosdkcore.jar')
}
```

**app gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ufasreader.cn.weiboclient"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':weiboSDK')
}
```

**settings gradle:**

```
    include ':weiboSDK'
    include ':weiboSDKDemo'
```

**project gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\drovorub\work\WeiboClient\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\sir\work\WeiboClient\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/sina/weibo/sdk/BuildConfig;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a purely english site, the link you're pointing at is Chinese. IMO, this question is too localized.

Comment: No, one does not need to follow the links to understand this.  The error is quite clear, though the poster chose the uninformative part of the message for the title (fixing that).